# how to add quotation marks for characters that are inside brackets and separated by a comma?

Tags: r, regex, string

The idea is to add quotation marks for all strings inside an string list representation.

Tried the next:

```
input_text <- "[innovation manager, manager director, senior manager]"

scan(text=input_text, what="")
```

Which returns:

```
'[innovation" "manager,"    "manager"     "director,"   "senior"      "manager]'
```

Expected output could look like this:

```
'["innovation manager", "manager director", "senior manager"]'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `paste0('["', paste(unlist(strsplit(substr(input_text, 2, nchar(input_text)-1), "\\s*,\\s*")), collapse='", "'),'"]')`, see https://ideone.com/bAuQoL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method - remove the square brackets with `gsub`, split at the `,` (`strsplit`), extract the list element, insert the double quotes (`dQuote`), and `paste` the split elements together

```
sprintf('[%s]', paste(dQuote(strsplit(gsub("[][]", "", input_text), 
        ",\\s*")[[1]], FALSE), collapse=", "))
```

-output

```
[1] "[\"innovation manager\", \"manager director\", \"senior manager\"]"
```

Comment: Hello @akrun, is there any way to remove the backlash from the string?

Comment: @AlvaroMartinez it is just the escape.  you can check with `cat(sprintf('[%s]', paste(dQuote(strsplit(gsub("[][]", "", input_text), 
        ",\\s*")[[1]], FALSE), collapse=", ")))`

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution;

```r
library(tidyverse)

input_text <- "[innovation manager, manager director, senior manager]"

input_text %>% 
  str_remove_all("\\[|\\]") %>% 
  str_split(", ") %>% unlist

#> [1] "innovation manager" "manager director"   "senior manager"
```

But, if the OP wants the result as a single string, one can use the following:

```r
input_text %>% 
  str_remove_all("\\[|\\]") %>% 
  str_split(", ") %>%
  map(~ str_c('"',.x, '"')) %>% unlist %>% 
  str_flatten(collapse = ", ") %>% 
  str_c("[",.,"]")

#> [1] "[\"innovation manager\", \"manager director\", \"senior manager\"]"
```